# php file cannot be found during POST request

Tags: php, post, phonegap, html-framework-7

I am building a simple mobile app with Framework7 and Phonegap that submits form data to a database. I have created a form POST according to the [F7 docs](https://framework7.io/docs/form.html#send-form-data-on-submit) to a POST test server as follows:

```
<form action="https://ptsv2.com/t/c1i9p-1580217375/post" method="POST" class="form-ajax-submit">
```

I can see in the console that the form data looks correct and the test server is also receiving the data:

[image]

I am now trying to create a connection to phpMyAdmin running locally so that I can POST the data somewhere. My HTML has changed to:

```
<form action="/php/form-data.php" method="POST" class="form-ajax-submit">
```

And the php file is as follows:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "test";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

//Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

//Insert generic variables into table for testing 
$sql = "INSERT INTO meeting (first_name, surname, email) 
        VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'johndoe@gmail.com')";

mysqli_close($conn);
```

The POST now fails and I am getting the following error in the console:

```
POST http://myIP:55/php/form-data.php 404 (Not Found)
```

If I click on the above link the php file in question downloads to my PC, so I don't think it's actually an issue of not being able to find the file and rather something wrong with the php or database? It is my first time ever doing a POST request so please excuse any silly mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install server for PHP e.g. Apache